# Way to use $ionicLoading.show() for an external link

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic sideview app. Every time I click on external link to open up from my app then my app stops(simply it hangs) for upto 2-5 seconds before opening the link. I want to use $ionicLoading feature at that point.
So **Is there any way that I can use $ionicLoading.show() until an external link fully opened?**
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bind an event to the anchor with ng-click?

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" ng-click="startLoading()">StackOverflow</a>
```

Comment: I have tried this type of thing but it doesn't actually work out.

Comment: You could fake the linking, so that on press the loading first appears, you use setTimeout for 100ms and then try and open the webpage.

Comment: when the external link starts to open I see a white page even if I have used $ionicLoading where else at that time the color of the window of app should be black.

Comment: thanks,  but this code isn't working on my side. I am not navigating to any link. Just a loading screen